# how we can proof this equality about stirling number?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$2\leq k<n:$

> $$\begin{align}
> \sum\limits_{i=0}^{k+1}(-1)^i{k+1\choose i}(k+1-i)^n
> &=\bigg[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2}(-1)^i{2\choose i}(2-i)^2\bigg]{n\choose 2}~+
> \\
> &+\bigg[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2}(-1)^i{2\choose i}(2-i)^3\bigg]{n\choose 3}~+
> \\
> &+~\cdots~+
> \\
> &+\bigg[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2}(-1)^i{2\choose i}(2-i)^{n-k+1}\bigg]{n\choose n-k+1}.
> \end{align}$$